# Is $\neg Con(PA)$ true in a model of $PA+\neg Con(PA)$?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

It is known that if Peano arithmetic (PA) is consistent then [$PA+\neg Con(PA)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737399/conpa-implies-consistency-of-mathsfpa-%C2%ACcon-mathsfpa) is also consistent. One way we can express $Con(PA)$ is $\forall x(\neg P(x))$ where $P(x)$ expresses that *$x$ encodes a proof of $0=1$*. We prove PA is consistent by proving there is one contradiction we can't prove, namely, $0=1 \land 0\neq 1$. If PA were inconsistent we could prove any contradiction.

I want to use a different contradiction. Let $Q(x)$ express that *$x$ encodes a proof of $\exists x(S(x)=0)$*. Given a proof of $\exists x(S(x)=0)$, I can easily derive the contradiction $\exists x(S(x)=0) \land \forall x(S(x) \neq 0)$ in the language of PA. Let $M$ be a model of $PA + \exists x(Q(x))$.

Is $\exists x(S(x)=0)$ actually true in $M$ in the sense there is an $x \in M$ whose successor is $0$? Or is the nonstandard length proof of $\exists x(S(x)=0)$ simply wrong?

---

I think Willemien brings up a valid concern. This concern is why I asked this question. Assume I state $\exists x(Q(x))$ the way Asaf suggests. $Q(x)$ would be an extremely complex arithmetic formula that assumes $x$ encodes a finite (in the model) sequence of finite sentences. $Q(x)$ will have a finite number of huge constants that encode theorems of the theory, etc. $Q(x)=1$ if $x$ encodes a proof of $\exists x(S(x)=0)$ otherwise $Q(x)=0$.

What if this $x$ is a standard natural number? This would mean our "model" has a finite (in the standard model) length proof of inconsistency and is actually inconsistent. The only way $PA+\exists x(Q(x))$ can have a model is if we assume $x$ is non-standard. There is no way to state this assumption in the language of PA. What if $x$ is not the shortest proof of a contradiction? Again, the axiom does not require $x$ to be the shortest proof of $\neg Con(PA)$.

I want to accept Carl Mummert's answer but I am still confused as to why $M \vDash \text{Bew}(\# \phi)$ is different from $M \vDash \phi$. It seems irrelevent that $\# \phi$ encodes the sentence $\phi$. If $\phi$ is a proof of $\exists x(S(x)=0)$, how is it different from any other proof? Is $\phi$ simply too long to be considered a valid proof?

Comment: what do you mean by " Let $Q(x) = x$ encodes a proof of $\exists x(S(x)=0)$. " and can you formulate that in PA?

Comment: @Willemien: If $\varphi$ is a sentence in the language of arithmetic, using Godel numbering and encoding recursive constructions into integers we can decide whether or not a particular number encodes a finite sequence of sentences, each is either from a collection of axioms (described as a collection of Godel numbers, of course) or deduced using some basic inference rules from things that appeared before that in the sequence. All that, and in fact more, can be formalized in the language of arithmetic using $\sf PA$. Since $\exists x(Sx=0)$ is such sentence, we can do it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know it is possible to formulate $\lnot Con (PA) $ or $ \exists x Q(x) $ where (x)=x encodes a proof of $ \exists x(S(x)=0)$ but the answer does depend IMHO on how exactly this extra axiom is formulated (does PA +  extra axiom  imply $ \exists x(S(x)=0)$ or not ?) if PA +  extra axiom  doesn't imply $ \exists x(S(x)=0)$ there is no problem, the system stays consistent so there is a model, if PA + extra axiom  does imply $\exists x (S(x) = 0) $ the system gets inconsistent so no model exist. two quite different answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say that $\text{Bew}(x)$ means "$x$ codes a formula, and that formula is provable in PA".

Let $\phi$ be a formula and $M$ be a model of PA. There is a very significant difference between
$$M \vDash \text{Bew}(\phi)$$
and
$$M \vDash \phi.$$

It is a common, false intuition to think $\text{Bew}(\phi)$ implies $\phi$. The scheme that includes all statements of the form $\text{Bew}(\phi) \to \phi$ is known as a *reflection* scheme. Relatively few instances of that scheme are provable in PA.

In fact, by [Löb's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem), the only way for $\text{Bew}(\phi) \to \phi$ to be provable in PA is for $\phi$ itself to be provable in PA.

Moreover, say $M$ is a model of $\lnot \text{Con}(\text{PA})$ (that is, a model of $\text{Bew}(0=1)$). Because PA proves $0=1 \to \phi$ for every $\phi$, this model $M$ will satisfy $\text{Bew}(\phi)$ for every $\phi$. But $M$ cannot satisfy every formula! So $M$ already shows you that the entire reflection scheme cannot be provable in PA.

In particular, this $M$ will satisfy $\text{Bew}((\exists x)[x+1=0])$ but (since it is a model of PA) it will not satisfy $(\exists x)[x+1=0]$.

It is true, of course, that if $\phi$ is provable from PA then $\phi$ is true in every model of PA. But $\text{Bew}(\phi)$ is only an imitation of the real "provable" predicate.

---

#### Soundness

We say that a logic is sound if, when the logic proves a formula, the formula is true in every model. There is another sense of soundness for theories of arithmetic. A theory of arithmetic is sound *for a given class of formulas* if, whenever the theory proves a formula in that class, the formula is true (true in the standard model of arithmetic).

$\lnot \text{Con}(\text{PA})$ is a formula in the syntactic class $\Sigma^0_1$. Any theory that proves this is, therefore, not sound for $\Sigma^0_1$ formulas. This notion of soundness, and a few others, are discussed in the Wikipedia article on [ω-consistent theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory).

Answer (score 1):

No, of course there is no such $x$ in $M$. Recall that $M$ is still a model of $\sf PA$.

Remember that when you talk about $\operatorname{Con}\sf(PA)$ you are talking about what $M$ internally thinks is the axioms of Peano. If $M$ is non-standard, as in this case, it will also have non-standard axioms. And these might be the ones contributing to the inconsistency. But from the external point of view, where the truth in $M$ is defined, these non-standard axioms are meaningless.

Comment: But $M$ thinks the proof is valid so the theory of $M$ is not [sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness#Arithmetic_soundness)?

Comment: You're confusing theory with meta-theory. What $M$ thinks is irrelevant for soundness. $M$ is a model in a universe which satisfy $\operatorname{Con}\sf (PA)$, since that universe knows about a model of $\sf PA$, standard or not. The soundness happens in the larger universe, not internally in $M$.

Comment: @Carl: There's a difference between "The theory of $M$ is not sound" and "$M$ thinks that $\sf PA$ is not sound", which I think is exactly what Russell is confused about.