# How does consistency PA+¬Con(PA) implies consistency of PA?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms, incompleteness

There is a [question on stack overflow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737399/conpa-implies-consistency-of-mathsfpa-%C2%ACcon-mathsfpa) showing that if PA is consistent then PA+¬Con(PA) is also consistent.
The thing is, that it should also work vice versa, that if PA+¬Con(PA) is consistent, then PA should also be consistent, but I cфnnot understand how that works or how it could be prooven.

Comment: If $T+\varphi$ is consistent, then in particular, $T$ is consistent. You can't prove a contradiction with less axioms if you couldn't prove a contradiction before.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila oh. Yeah sorry, it was just this straightforward. I was trying to overengineer the proof, sorry.